# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated False When Debugging in VS2012 Using IISExpress

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, iis-express

I have an older ASP.NET WebForms application that is trying to authenticate users. The application works perfectly in staging and production. However, when attempting to use IISExpress to debug locally, it doesn't.

There's a user control that is placed within a master page that contains a Login server control. The Login server control has a custom template and calls **LoginControl_Authenticate** during the **OnAuthenticate** event. There is one other server event called **LoginControl_LoggedIn** that is called during the **OnLoggedIn** event. Here's the code for those two methods:

```
Private Sub LoginControl_LoggedIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.Redirect("~/VerifyAuthentication.aspx", True)
End Sub

Private Sub LoginControl_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AuthenticateEventArgs)
    Dim loginCtrl As Login = CType(LoginContainer.FindControl("LoginControl"), Login)
    Dim username As String = loginCtrl.UserName
    Dim password As String = loginCtrl.Password
    e.Authenticated = Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)
End Sub
```

The VerifyAuthentication.aspx page is supposed to then validate the user and do some crazy profile population. On **Page_Load**, the first statement is to check **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated**. Again, locally, this is returning **False** every time. However, in production, it works as expected. Below is a snippet of this method:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(s as Object, e as EventArgs)
    If (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = False) Then
        ...
    End If
    ...
End Sub
```

The web.config is configured as described below:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." validation="SHA1"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" timeout="600" defaultUrl="/VerifyAuthentication.aspx" loginUrl="/" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" domain="localhost" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultSqlMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="DefaultSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Encrypted" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="60" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
    ...
</system.web>
```

As a side note, IIS Express is running this application as localhost:1800.

**EDIT (11.14.2013 10:00 AM EST)**

At Scott's request, I did verify both the local and production versions in Fiddler. In both versions, the response being sent back is for Set-Cookie. However, only the production version is actually setting the cookie (meaning that the .ASPXAUTH cookie appears in the cookie collection for the public version).

**EDIT (11/14/2013 11:30 AM EST)**
Yes. Here are the response and request headers:

*Local Development*

From the login:

```
Response sent 278 bytes of Cookie data:
            Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=AE66DCD41A34991EA27494478D779955ECE7AE3195BC5FE4F19085E9DC3307AF754D540A3B04504DBE65F79F1CFB3FA57780E807D4FA4D8BBD79E09A30BBE40BE4A8D76D26EC3F4FDD335A3667770E3CF7C8D8ACDD3E08B3D5A6B4F076EE5E638B6913DA774A662D300F9E1B554147F9E50D7B65; domain=localhost; path=/; HttpOnly
```

From VerifyAuthentication.aspx

```
Request sent 42 bytes of Cookie data:

ASP.NET_SessionId=udyfmuy3xg5k3145khptvxer
```

*Production*

From the login:

```
Response sent 291 bytes of Cookie data:
            Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=A34B5A519F2357269239544D4BFAE6DA30C9681F4F2C38D9574F747940C9F27F408AF2BB4A79437DFAB30E18E157D7C7291B1A4BFB98485C93F6427C6851737E8F3C35368A11C053BB5F9E48A0535D5178F10AB9E802C7956C80565F1B2CA042DE51228EF62CAB6B9E3AC748FDA87895B1C3D190; domain=mydomain.com; path=/; HttpOnly
```

From VerifyAuthentication.aspx

```
Request sent 286 bytes of Cookie data:

ASP.NET_SessionId=ex03esugzcdjuk55tevnfq3o; .ASPXAUTH=A34B5A519F2357269239544D4BFAE6DA30C9681F4F2C38D9574F747940C9F27F408AF2BB4A79437DFAB30E18E157D7C7291B1A4BFB98485C93F6427C6851737E8F3C35368A11C053BB5F9E48A0535D5178F10AB9E802C7956C80565F1B2CA042DE51228EF62CAB6B9E3AC748FDA87895B1C3D190
```

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to inspect the HTTP traffic to and fro? Specifically you want to check whether on login the server is sending back a `Set-Cookie` HTTP header and when redirected to `VerifyAuthentication.aspx` whether the client is send back a `Cookie` HTTP header.

Comment: Can you post the response of the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header as well as the URLs of the request on both the production and test environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that it has to do with using “localhost” in .config for the cookie’s domain.